# Instalação do Magento dando erro de php extension

Tags: php, magento, xampp

Estou rodando a instalação do Magento 2.0.1 no xampp v3.2.2, e quando irá fazer o check de php extension surge o seguinte erro conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Erro de php Extension]

Alguém já passou por esse problema pode auxiliar?

Comment: Habilita essas extensões no php.ini e reinicia o apache já deve funcionar. É so remver o `;` das linhas.

Comment: No site do PHP mostra as maneiras de fazer a instalação de cada biblioteca: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.xsl.php , http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.intl.php , http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.soap.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá no `php.ini` no Xampp, e procure as linhas (se for Windows):

```
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

> Se estiver no Windows abra o php.ini pelo notepad++ ou sublimetext, no bloco de notas do Windows não vai abrir direito devido a quebra de linhas

Se for Linux/Mac

```
;extension=xsl.so
;extension=soap.so
;extension=intl.so
```

Se for PHP7.2:

```
;extension=xsl
;extension=soap
;extension=intl
```

Então tire o `;` da frente e salve o `php.ini`, deve ficar assim (windows):

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Se for Linux/Mac

```
extension=xsl.so
extension=soap.so
extension=intl.so
```

Se for PHP7.2:

```
extension=xsl
extension=soap
extension=intl
```

Então reiniciei o Apache pelo painel do Xampp