# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found com PHP 7.2.x

Tags: php

Alguém saberia me falar como resolver este problema?

Quando acesso o meu endereço local do meu website, retorna está mensagem "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found". Essa mensagem só é retornada quando tento usar o PHP 7.2.1, pois estou tentando atualizar a versão do PHP.

Quando a versão PHP 7.1.x, está funcionando normalmente.

Já coloquei a DLL "php_com_dotnet.dll" no ext do PHP.

Comment: já colocou no php.ini também? `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll `

Comment: Coloquei sim...

Comment: Reiniciou o servidor? O `php.ini` que você alterou é o mesmo que aparece em `Loaded Configuration File` ao utilizar `<?php phpinfo();`?

Comment: Reiniciei sim... É este php.ini sim

Answer (score 2):

### As coisas mudaram no PHP7.2

Extensões no `php.ini` como

```
 extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Era um formato usado **até o PHP7.1**, mas a partir do PHP7.2 **todas extensões** agora usam um formato como estes:

```
extension=com_dotnet
```

Sem o prefixo `php_` e sem a extensão `.dll`, claro que na pasta `./ext` ainda deve ser manter os nomes com os formatos `php_<extensão>.dll` ou em linux `<extensão>.so`, mas no php.ini (**a partir do 7.2**) isto já é implícito, ou seja apenas o nome já irá reconhecer.

Assim como em outras extensões deve estar algo como:

```
extension=mysqli
```

Ao invés de:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

E ao invés de (em Linux e Mac)

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

Isto provavelmente foi feito para que os php.ini sejam mais "portáveis", como é descrito no próprio php.ini do PHP7.2 em diante:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename
;
; For example:
;
;   extension=mysqli
;
```

Este formato do PHP7.2 é usado tanto no Windows quanto em Linux e Mac

Inclusive eu sempre oriento em todas minhas respostas sobre as diferenças de Linux (e Mac), Windows e PHP7.2, por exemplo:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262167/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274476/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267249/3635

Comment: Coloquei como você dissem mas continuou dando o erro, peguei e atualizei para o PHP 7.2.2... Porém apresentou este erro "Warning: Use of undefined constant MSSERVER - assumed 'MSSERVER' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"... Sabe o q poderia ser?

Comment: @LucasSouza o `MSSERVER` foi escrito em algum script seu? Isso parece erro em seu script e não na ativação da extensão.

Comment: Não.. É um arquivo .inc que tem a variável $TipoDBConf atribuindo o valor MSSERVER

Comment: @LucasSouza esse MSSERVER provavelmente é algum código obsoleto que você pegou de algum lugar e não tem relação com o problema da extensão.

Comment: Ok... Obrigado Guilherme!